# Unable to determine absolute path of git directory

Tags: git

```
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false fetch origin

git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=false -c core.quotepath=false pull origin master
bash.exe: warning: could not find /tmp, please create!

/libexec/git-core/git-sh-setup: line 297: cd: .git: No such file or directory
```

Unable to determine absolute path of git directory

Comment: You really need to provide more details about your environment and what you're trying to do before we can answer this question.

Comment: can you just run `git init` before you pull anything to see if that is working